# ValueError: could not convert string to float: pythonGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, google-api-python-client

```
costOfItem = (Item1 * 10) + (Item2 * 20)\
                              + (Item3 * 30) + (Item4 * 40) + (Item5 * 50) + (Item6 * 60) + (Item7* 70) + (Item8* 80)
                 SubTotalofITEMS = "Rs.", str('%.2f'% costOfItem)

                 SubTotal.set(SubTotalofITEMS)
                 Tax="Rs.", str('%.2f'% ((costOfItem) * 0.08))
                 GSTTax.set(Tax)
                 TTax = ((costOfItem) * 0.08)

                 TCost = "Rs.", ('%.2f'% (costOfItem + TTax))
                 TotalCost.set(TCost)
```

I'll Makaing Python GUI Restront billing management system.But I'M facing problem to costofItem in calculation.....

```
 **strong text**
   Error showing 
    t__.py", line 1705, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Py.Billing system - Copy.py", line 252, in costOfItem
        Item1=float(Tea.get())
    ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
costOfItem = (Item1 * 10) + (Item2 * 20)\
                              + (Item3 * 30) + (Item4 * 40) + (Item5 * 50) + (Item6 * 60) + (Item7* 70) + (Item8* 80)
                 SubTotalofITEMS = "Rs.", str('%.2f'% costOfItem)

                 SubTotal.set(SubTotalofITEMS)
                 Tax="Rs.", str('%.2f'% ((costOfItem) * 0.08))
                 GSTTax.set(Tax)
                 TTax = ((costOfItem) * 0.08)

                 TCost = "Rs.", str('%.2f'% (costOfItem + TTax))
                 TotalCost.set(TCost)
```

Comment: Now, I Find the Error, It's work properly... TCost = "Rs.", str('%.2f'% (costOfItem + TTax))

Answer (score 1):

The value that you are trying to convert to a float from a string is likely not a number, you can check for this by using the built-in method [isnumeric](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric)

As for what the value currently contains I wouldn't know but I would suggest printing the value before it fails to see if it is a value you are not expecting.

```py
x = Tea.get()
if x.isnumeric():
    float(x)
else:
    print(f"x is not a float is is: {x}")
```

Comment: I am not telling you that is the answer I'm telling you that whatever you are trying to convert is not a number.